# Downgrade conda on mac not permitted

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I am working on mac, trying to downgrade python (from anaconda) from 3.7 to 3.6 and I get an error.

on the terminal, I wrote: conda install python=3.6.8.

Error:

```
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::python.app-2-py37_9'.
PermissionError(1, 'Operation not permitted')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/../anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo' -> '/Users/../anaconda3/python.app/Contents/PkgInfo.c~'
```

I tried:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda update conda


sudo conda install python=3.6


sudo -H conda update conda


conda update conda
```

still, get the same error.
what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, I would probably execute the 
    `conda search python`
command in the terminal to check out if conda actually sees all Python versions available(which it should be).
Afterwards you should try using `sudo conda install python=3.6.0` instead of `sudo conda install python=3.6`. It might help 
*OR* you can simply create a new environment and install a separate Python version there[You can find the official description here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python)